# Scala how to get the key of Map where value as List

Tags: scala

I have Map like this:

```
val myMap = Map(
    testKey1 -> List(testValue1, testValue2, testValue3....), 
    testKey2 -> List(testValue4, testValue5, testValue6....),
    testKey3 -> List(testValue7, testValue8, testValue9....)
)
```

I want to do some exact matching of the list value and get the corresponding key of map.

Like example: I want to check if '**testValue9**' is in this Map then I will get the key '**testKey3**'.

I think it could be solvable by this way but I can't iterate through list's value to check the value is there or not. 
Or could someone please give me some hints.

```
myMap foreach {
          case (key, List(_)) => println( key )
          case _ =>    
        }
```

Comment: As a general comment Map is rather a poor choice of data structure for this use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to find a single value in a `Map` you can use `find`:

```
  myMap.find(_._2.contains(value)).map(_._1)
```

This will return `Some(key)` if the value is found, otherwise `None`.

If you think there may be multiple matching values, you can replace `find` with `filter`

```
  myMap.filter(_._2.contains(value)).map(_._1)
```

or use `collect`

```
  myMap.collect{ case (k, v) if v.contains(value) =>  k }
```

In both cases this will return a list of all matching keys and will depend on how `Map` is implemented.

Note that the `filter` option can be expressed using a `for` expression, which does exactly the same thing:

```
  for { (k,v) <- myMap if v.contains(value) } yield k
```

In most cases it is just a question of style as to which is better, though the `collect` is likely to perform best.

#### Update

Raman Mishra helpfully points out that the filter version can be simplified to

```
myMap.filter(_._2.contains(value)).keys
```

This returns `Set` rather than `List` which is more appropriate because the order is not significant.

Comment: the map(_._1) is not necessary in filter we can use .keys

Comment: I like that the solution provides an example that works for the case that a Map may have potentially differently long lists.

Answer (score 3):

you want to do this i think:

Assuming Key is String and the value is List[String]

```
val keyContainsValue: immutable.Iterable[String] = myMap map {
    case (key, value) => if (value.contains(testValue9)) key else ""
  }
```

you can use empty string as the defalut value so that you can get the return type as iterable[String].

As i don't know the type of your key and value you can use option too. For that purpose like this.

```
val keyContainsValue: immutable.Iterable[Option[String]] = myMap map {
        case (key, value) => if (value.contains(testValue9)) Some(key) else None
      }
println(keyContainsValue.flatten) //you will get the list of keys which contains the value specified.
```

Comment: Your `case _` is unnecessary because the first `case` will always match. And using `collect` would avoid the need to create a default value and then remove it again.

Answer (score 1):

```
val searchValue = "testValue9"

myMap.collect{ case (key, values) if values.contains(searchValue) => key }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like

```
val getKeys = (k: String) => for (m<- myMap.keys;
                                 v<- myMap(m);
                                 if v==k) yield m
```

Comment: Why iterate through the keys and then lookup the value? Better to just iterate through the key/value pairs.

Comment: since the value is a list and I wanted to iterate on that. It is true though that using contains is more efficient since it short circuits